# jquery $('.class').each() how many items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When looping over a group of items using jquery selectors is there a way to find out how many items there are on the collection?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you're using chained syntax:

```
$(".class").each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

...I don't think there's any (reasonable) way for the code within the `each` function to know how many items there are. (*Unreasonable* ways would involve repeating the selector and using `index`.)

But it's easy enough to make the collection available to the function that you're calling in `each`. Here's one way to do that:

```
var collection = $(".class");
collection.each(function() {
    // You can access `collection.length` here.
});
```

As a somewhat convoluted option, you could convert your jQuery object to an array and then use the array's `forEach`. The arguments that get passed to `forEach`'s callback are the entry being visited (what jQuery gives you as `this` and as the *second* argument), the index of that entry, and the array you called it on:

```
$(".class").get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
    // Here, array.length is the total number of items
});
```

That assumes an at least *vaguely* modern JavaScript engine and/or a shim for `Array#forEach`.

Or for that matter, give yourself a new tool:

```
// Loop through the jQuery set calling the callback:
//    loop(callback, thisArg);
// Callback gets called with `this` set to `thisArg` unless `thisArg`
// is falsey, in which case `this` will be the element being visited.
// Arguments to callback are `element`, `index`, and `set`, where
// `element` is the element being visited, `index` is its index in the
// set, and `set` is the jQuery set `loop` was called on.
// Callback's return value is ignored unless it's `=== false`, in which case
// it stops the loop.
$.fn.loop = function(callback, thisArg) {
    var me = this;
    return this.each(function(index, element) {
        return callback.call(thisArg || element, element, index, me);
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
$(".class").loop(function(element, index, set) {
    // Here, set.length is the length of the set
});
```

Comment: Or, store the `length` value itself in the outer scope.

Comment: @Matt: But to do that, and also call `each`, I'll still need to at least temporarily store the collection itself. And why *not* do so?

Comment: Yeah, the only solution. I've always thought jQuery should supply the collection as an extra argument to the callback.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `.length` property. It is **not** a function.

```
alert($('.class').length); // alerts a nonnegative number
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my above to reflect that .length is a property.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a version of jQuery that is less than version 1.8 you can use the  $('.class').size() which takes zero parameters. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/size/) for more information on .size() method. 
However if you are using (or plan to upgrade) to 1.8 or greater you can use $('.class').length property. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/length/) for more information on .length property.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like `length` or `size()`?

Refs: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: I think, he means **within** loop.

Comment: length is an attribute, not a function. size() is a function that returns length.

Comment: @Matt "when looping". I'm not sure such feature would have a lot of practical use, though.

Comment: no, but for educational purposes, $.each(coll,function(index,value){}); , could use index at the last iteration

Comment: @Orbit how do you know when it's the last iteration?