# How to add iFrame attributes, that will not validate as HTML5, via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have some iFrames on an HTML5 page, each with the class "a-iframe". There are about 4 of these frames, all of different shapes and sizes, on the page.

How do I get each of these frames, by class name and apply these attributes, that will not validate in HTML by W3C validator:

```
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
```

My current code, that does not work right, is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.each($(".a-iframe"), function() 
    {   
        $(this).attr({
            scrolling: "no",
            frameborder: "0",
            allowtransparency: "true"
        });     
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".a-iframe").each(function() {   
    $(this).attr({
      scrolling: "no",
      frameborder: "0",
      allowtransparency: "true"
    });
    console.log($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="#" class="a-iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Nope, with the iframe pointing to a page with more content or margins, then the iframe allows for, the scrollbars still show up. I can't use the "inline" attributes you have placed in the `<iframe>` tag because html5 validation will fail. scrolling, frameborder, and allowtransparency, are all deprecated. Which I don't understand, really, because there are no replacements for them in standard css.

Comment: of course there are! `overflow: hidden` `border: none`

Comment: You can get CSS properties via `$(selector).css('propertyName');`

Answer (score 0):

After I play your codes for awhile, I observed on jsfiddle that maybe it's because whether the scrollbar is showed or not is determined when content load-in, not when attribute is set, so I altered to this:

Edited: These code will work on my web:

```
$('.a-iframe').attr({
    scrolling: "no",
    frameborder: "0",
    allowtransparency: "true"
  });
```

When use selector, you'll get the array of all that mets the selector, and jquery functions can apply to them all at once.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.a-iframe').attr({
    scrolling: "no",
    frameborder: "0",
    allowtransparency: "true"
  });
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe class="a-iframe" src="https://jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
<iframe data-aa="74836" class="a-iframe" src="https://ad.a-ads.com/74836?size=468x60" style="width:468px;height:60px;border:0px;border-width:0px;border-style:none;bor‌​der-color:transparent;background-color:#FFFFFF;overflow:hidden !important;padding: 0px !important;margin: 0px !important;"></iframe>
<iframe class="a-iframe" src="https://validator.w3.org/check"></iframe>
```

Comment: I cannot change the src on-the-fly like that. even if I tried `$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));` it may still try to load the frame twice. And the scrollbars  sill exist! Stubborn scrollbars! Will `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` help this issue at all? Look at [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Does the second time load not makes the iframe scroll bar disappear? Maybe you can alter my jsfiddle example to demonstrate what limits do you have?

Comment: idk, all the iframes have different source values. Is there another way to reload without changing the source? Though, I really can't reload the source content anyway because the sites pointed to by the iframes, count and monitor impressions (i.e. page loads), so double-page-loads, on every page-load, will not be feasible, for me.

Comment: Did you define any css rule? If I put it on my example, it just show no scrollbar even I get rid of all the js :S

Comment: jsFiddle does not (in this case anyway) display an accurate representation of what you would see if you upload a html file with a presized iFrame, on your own server. They have to limit some user code, because of all the nice little hackers out there who try to exploit them, with malicious js.

Comment: Ok, I'll run them on my server to get a look.

Comment: a more logical way of checking is to set the 'inline' code inside the frames (*you need at least 3 iframes*) to `scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" allowtransparency="false" ` and try to turn them all off via JQuery. BTW check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148509/jquery-class-each-how-many-items) out. Is it possible it's just not iterating through them all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81297/discussion-between-fuyushimoya-and-james-anderson-jr).